# syntax error, unexpected 'something' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php

Why I'm getting this error?

> > syntax error, unexpected '$flag' (T_VARIABLE)

```
    while(odbc_fetch_row($result))
    {
        $name = odbc_result($result,"CharName");
        $lvl = odbc_result($result,"CharLevel");
        $class = odbc_result($result,"CharClass");
        $flag = 0;
        for($i=0;$i<count($gms);$i++)
        {
            if($name = $gms[$i]
                $flag = 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: use an IDE to avoid this kind of mistakes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you have a syntax error here**

```
if($name = $gms[$i]
```

change to

```
if($name == $gms[$i])
```

wich is causing `T_VARIABLE` error, just close bracket and add `=` and you are ready to go

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed bracket after if condition

```
if($name = $gms[$i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for($i=0;$i<count($gms);$i++)
        {
            if($name == $gms[$i])//closing paranthesis and '==' to compare  
                $flag = 1;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `)` paranthesis. Change this line from

```
if($name = $gms[$i]
        $flag = 1;
```

To,

```
if($name = $gms[$i])
        $flag = 1;
```